# How to re-name of Expo-AV Record (FileSystem)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on a record app using expo (react native).

I'm recording using [expo-av](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/audio/) it's work perfectly *(recording sounds & playing records)*.

My problem is all records are saved under this title :

> **recording-*.3gp** *(for example: recording-c860412c-8ce7-4975-8fb7.3gp)*

But for some reasons, I want to change the title of the record on the System File to :

> **NameOfApp-*.3pg**

Anyone could help me to change the file (record) name, Thanks!

Comment: Aren't the files already saved in a sandbox for the specific app? Meaning they don't need to be prefixed with the app name? Anyway, it doesn't seem the expo-av API supports renaming but you can probably use [FileSystem.move](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemmoveasyncoptions) after the recording is done to rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var oldFileName = `${recording-*.3gp}`;
var newFileName = str.replace("recording", "NameOfApp");
```

then use this new file name to save as a file

Comment: this is how I save record and get record URI:                           
"    await this.recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    const info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(this.recording.getURI()); "

Comment: You can convert the string to uri. and do what you want. In question you just asked how to rename. So update your problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

I Found it!
I should just "move" the file and specify the name I want as the destination : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemmoveasyncoptions